# html5 game engine, cocos2d vs construct2

Tags: cordova, construct, cocos2d-html5

Just a beginners question, I am looking into html5 game engine for mobile devices, possible integration with Phonegap. mainly targeting iphone5 and iOS 7, I see that cocos2d is 2d only, but the question is construct2 vs cocos2d-html. if only consider 2d which is better, performances, learning curves etc.

Comment: I am thinking about purchasing construct2 to do some HTML5 programming with. Does it show the HTML code in the editor so that you can learn or is it one of those things that a lot of things happen behind the scenes.

Comment: No, but you can still view content of exported html file.